# This is a dictionaries exercise. I'm confused on how to do this. Can anybody help me with this question?

Tags: python, dictionary, inventory

Given the following dictionary:

```
inventory = {
    'gold' : 500,
    'pouch' : ['flint', 'twine', 'gemstone'],
    'backpack' : ['xylophone', 'dagger', 'bedroll', 'bread loaf']}
```

Do the following:

1. Add a key to inventory called 'pocket' and set the value of 'pocket' to be a list consisting of the strings 'seashell', 'strange berry', and 'lint'.
2. Sort the items in the 'backpack' key.
3. Remove the value “dagger” from the ‘backpack’ key
4. Add 50 to the number stored under the 'gold' key
5. Display the dictionary
   Make sure to watch the video to show you the dictionary methods

Comment: What exactly is the difficulty you have encountered when you did this?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with item #1... Your Keys are the first items (gold, pouch, backpack) so since pocket will need a list it will be similar to the last two. So step one is figure out how to add a new item. Just take the problem step by step and when you run into a specific issue come back and ask!

Comment: What kind of answer are you seeking? I'm not going to tell you how to do your homework because that's not going to help you at all, but this does point you in the right direction. You can't expect someone to solve the problem for you, but there are many people who will answer specific questions or point you in the right direction (like I did here)